# JSON Image in new Actity

Tags: android, json, image, bitmap

I have a sample of my JSON file(it is pretty big so I will not show all of it) like this.

```
[ 
   {
    "name":"Costel Pantilimon",
     "position":"GK",
     "age":"28",
     " number":"1",
     "photo":"images/costel_pantilimon.png"
    },
    {
     "name":"Vito Mannone",
     "position":"GK",
     "age":"27",
     "number":"25",
     "photo":"images/Mannone.png"
     }
]
```

I display all the JSON objects in a listview.

[image: JSON listview]

I click on the first row and the name of the player is shown in a new activity in a simple textview. So far so good. The problem is that I want to display the image too,and I am strugling with this one.

Here is a part of my code that does this webservice job.

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,    
 long id) {
    String details = playersList.get(position).getDetails();

    //Log.d("Theo", details);

    switch (position) {
        case 0:

            Intent i = new Intent(PlayersList.this, ExtraInfo.class);
            i.putExtra("details", details);


            startActivity(i);
            break;

    }
   }
   private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Players>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (tasks.size() == 0) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        tasks.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Players> doInBackground(String... params) {

        String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        playersList = PlayersJSONParser.parseFeed(content);

        for (Players p : playersList) {
            try {
                String imageUrl = PHOTOS_BASE_URL +p.getPhoto();
                InputStream in = (InputStream) new 
    URL(imageUrl).getContent();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                p.setBitmap(bitmap);
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        return playersList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Players> result) {

        tasks.remove(this);
        if (tasks.size() == 0) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (result == null) {
            Toast.makeText(PlayersList.this, "Web service not available", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        playersList = result;
        updateDisplay();

    }

 }
```

And the activity that actually displays the name is

```
public class ExtraInfo extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView detailsText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_extra_info);

    detailsText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    String details = getIntent().getStringExtra("details");
    Log.d("Extra info", details);

    detailsText.setText("" + details);

  }

}
```

Any ideas on how to pass the image in the new activity?

Thank you for reading my question,

Theo

Comment: no big deal. Bitmap is parcelable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **4 Solutions** to solve this problem

**1. Image to ByteArray then ByteArray to Image.**

First Convert Image into Byte Array and then pass into Intent and in next activity get byte array from Bundle and Convert into Image(Bitmap) and set into ImageView.

Convert Bitmap to Byte Array :

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Pass byte array into intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**2. First Save image into SDCard and in next activity set this image into ImageView.**

**3. Convert the Image to Base64 and then pass with Intent as a String, then again decode the string back to bitmap to set to imageview.**

To encode image to Base64 :

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedBitmap = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedBitmap;
    }
```

To decode Base64 to bitmap :

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
    {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory
                .decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }
```

**4. Using Parcelable**

You can pass bitmap as parcelable.

To pass :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, youractivty.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", yourBitmap);
```

To retrieve :

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Comment: Thing is I am bit confused on intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", yourBitmap). I don't know to get the "yourBitmap" variable. For a simple text ie name I can just write i.putExtra("name",playerstList.get(position).getName()).

Comment: @Theo No it will be like 
i.putExtra("name",playerstList.get(position).getBitmap());

Provided that your PlayersList must implement getter method of the same.

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you could always pass it in the intent:
Like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExtraInfo.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", yourBitmap);
```

and catch this intent in your activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

than set this bitmap to your image view